# Как нормально сделать распознавание треугольников с помощью open cv на python?

Tags: python, opencv

У меня есть две программы для распознавания треугольников на фотографии, но они работают не так, как я хочу. Суть программы - распознавать треугольники.
Первая программа не распознает треугольники, но зафиксировала 586 образов. Вторая программа не распознала треугольники, но распознала шестиугольник.
Фото на котором нужно распознать:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Первая программа:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("output_3.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
cv2.imwrite("gray.jpg", gray)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 250)
cv2.imwrite("edged.jpg", edged)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite("closed.jpg", closed)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(contours)
triangle = 0
total = 0
for i in contours:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(i, True)
    vertices = cv2.approxPolyDP(i, 0.02 * peri, True)
    total += 1
    if len(vertices) == 3:
        triangle += 1
        cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0),
                            3, cv2.LINE_AA, hierarchy, 1)
cv2.imshow('contours', image)
print(total)
print(triangle)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("output_4.jpg", image)
```

Вторая программа

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('output_3_1.png')  # read image from system
cv2.imshow('original', img)  # Displaying original image
cv2.waitKey(0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert to grayscale image
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 170, 255)  # Determine edges of objects in an image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
(contours, _) = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # Find contours in an image


def detectShape(c):  # Function to determine type of polygon on basis of number of sides
    shape = 'unknown'
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    vertices = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * peri, True)
    sides = len(vertices)
    if (sides == 3):
        shape = 'triangle'
    elif(sides == 4):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        aspectratio = float(w)/h
        if (aspectratio == 1):
            shape = 'square'
        else:
            shape = "rectangle"
    elif(sides == 5):
        shape = 'pentagon'
    elif(sides == 6):
        shape = 'hexagon'
    elif(sides == 8):
        shape = 'octagon'
    elif(sides == 10):
        shape = 'star'
    else:
        shape = 'circle'
    return shape


for cnt in contours:
    moment = cv2.moments(cnt)
    cx = int(moment['m10'] / moment['m00'])
    cy = int(moment['m01'] / moment['m00'])
    shape = detectShape(cnt)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, shape, (cx, cy), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0,0),2)  #Putting name of polygon along with the shape 
    cv2.imshow('polygons_detected', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, что в `vertices` у первой программы получается. Тогда может будет понятнее, что оно нашло вместо треугольников

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, в первой программе у вас один шаг лишний, вот этот:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite("closed.jpg", closed)
```

Если его вообще выпилить:

```
closed = edged
```

То получим такой результат:

```
688
281
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём тут дело? В том, что этот шаг слишком размывает треугольники и они превращаются в фигуры не с тремя вершинами, а явно больше:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если внимательно присмотреться к результатам этого шага, мы увидим скорее шестиугольники:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как починить второй код я не смог сходу разобраться.
Но вообще полезно отображать промежуточные картинки, получающиеся после преобразований, чтобы понимать, какие могут быть проблемы на каком шаге.

Comment: у меня треугольников всего 582, а детектится только 332. https://yadi.sk/d/JMeHLJ_V2EvBcg - там скрин и прога

Comment: @ZZaRRyaDD Ну, там надо дальше копать. Я так сходу не соображу, вы попробуйте сначала поменьше картинку взять, на такой большой сразу сложно понять что оно считает, а что нет. И я не спец в CV2, надо подобрать преобразование, которое соединит линии, но не испортит при этом фигуры. Это надо пробовать всякое, перебирать